# Downloading a file from Google cloud storage is corrupted randomly

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download data Bigquery data through Google cloud storage. Am able to send data from BigQuery to GCS but when downloading data from GCS to load the files are corrupted randomly.

```
getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
    out = fs.create(pathDir, true);                 
        getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
        boolean match= ismd5HashValid(o.getMd5Hash(), pathDir);
```

and to check md5 checksum

```
private boolean ismd5HashValid(String md5hash, String path) {
        org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path pathDir = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path);
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
             is = fs.open(pathDir);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes;
            while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                md.update(bytes, 0, numBytes);
            }
            byte[] digest = md.digest();
            String result = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(digest));
            Log.info("Source file md5hash {} Downloaded file md5hash {}", md5hash, result);         
            if (md5hash.equals(result)) {
                Log.info("md5hash check is valid");
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        }
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: A few questions: First, if you download the file via gsutil or Google Cloud Console, do you get the MD5 you expect? Second: is it a gzip file?

Comment: @Brandon 1. MD5 value of the file is not matching with the downloaded file. example - Source file md5hash 8gmCoZuvcKlQSf83SUO0JQ== Downloaded file md5hash iZnNF2ICJn9NmUKxNlxtHg== 2.yes it is a gzip file.

Comment: Interesting! Does the gzip'd file contain only a single file? Does the MD5 of the unzipped content match?

Comment: @brandon It's a  single file gzipped. The file is corrupted so I could not open it to check md5 value.